# How to configure an out of date system to install software with apt?

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, repository, 18.10

Having an out-of-date system, yet [looking](https://askubuntu.com/q/1141879/45156) to install [alpine](http://alpine.x10host.com/alpine/) with `apt`.

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ apt-cache search alpine
nano - small, friendly text editor inspired by Pico
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ head -n 1 /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu cosmic main
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.10
Release:    18.10
Codename:   cosmic
thufir@dur:~$
```

I'm [missing](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2346051) repo's?  Assuming so, what needs to be added to simply install alpine?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to install software or upgrade from an old unsupported release?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91815/how-to-install-software-or-upgrade-from-an-old-unsupported-release)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 18.04 sources.list:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list /home/user/sources.list.bk
sudo vi /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Paste the repositories to it:

```
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates main restricted
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Then update packages and install alpine:

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt install alpine
```

Alpine is installed and starts correctly:

```
$ alpine
Creating subdirectory "/home/spacer/mail" where Alpine will store
its mail folders.
Alpine finished -- Closed empty folder "INBOX"

user@ubuntu18:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release 
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.10
DISTRIB_CODENAME=cosmic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.10"
```

Also, as FedonKadifeli suggested in comment, [you could do the next](https://askubuntu.com/a/91821/925971):

> If you want to continue using an outdated release then edit
>   `/etc/apt/sources.list` and change `archive.ubuntu.com` and
>   `security.ubuntu.com` to `old-releases.ubuntu.com`

But it as it is actually didn't work for me.

Comment: why bionic and not cosmic?

Comment: @Thufir there's no usual cosmic repositories. But you could use them exchanging `us.archive` to `old-releases`. To check what is available there, open in browser: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/